# Leave login URL for my user beautiful

Tags: urls

Good afternoon, I've been here for a long time trying to keep my website's login
URL as example: [www.meusite.com.br/entrar](http://www.meusite.com.br/entrar), but the URL presented to my user when he clicks on the login button
appears: [www.meusite.com](http://www.meusite.com). br/entrar/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fradiomandeladigital.com.br

Detail the registration URL is perfectly fine

[image]

[image]

See that the register URL is correct, pretty short, but the login URL is ridiculously horrible

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to get rid of the `?redirect_to={url}`, you can use the [`login_url` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_url/) to change the login URL, and remove unwanted querystring components with [`remove_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_query_arg/):

```php
add_filter( 'login_url', 'wpse422493_strip_login_url' );
/**
 * Strips `redirect_to` from the querystring.
 *
 * @param  string $url The login URL.
 * @return string      The filtered login URL.
 */
function wpse422493_strip_login_url( $url ) {
    return remove_query_arg( 'redirect_to', $url );
}
```

**Note:** This code is *untested* and intended as a starting point only, not as finished, production-ready code. Make sure you test it in a non-production environment before you use it in production.